# Only one project accessible where projects share a namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a solution which contains say, *DataAccess* and *DataAccessImplementation*

*DataAccess* contains: IFooAccess and other Interfaces

*DataAccessImplementation* contains: FooAccess which implements IFooAccess, along with lots of other classes that do the same.

Now, both of these projects are in the same Namespace.. 'foo.DataAccess'.

The problem I've got is, in my project that references these projects, only one of these two projects is going into the bin folder at a time when I build and only it's interfaces are available in my code. If I include a reference to *DataAccess* and *DataAccessImplementation*, only *DataAccess* will show for example.

*DataAccessImplementation* won't go in until I unreference *DataAccess*, but as soon as I reference it again, the only classes I can find are that of the *DataAccess* project.

Do these projects need to be in seperate namespaces? Why are the two projects not being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually no they don't have to be - but it isn't best practice to keep them in one namespace either. To be clear (for ourselves and other developers) we separate them according to their **focus** or **intent**. For instance:

```
com.yournamespace.DataAccess
```

and

```
com.yournamespace.DataModels
```

These will be two separate projects. In this example I've replaced your 'DataAccessImplementation' with DataModels because the distinction isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having wasn't actually due to the namespaces, it was instead the assembly name that was the same. After changing the names to those more appropriate, it worked fine.